# Is there a way to view or work with the revision history of answers?

Tags: discussion

I know that the revision history of questions is editable and viewable. Is this also possible for answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the traditional way is to click the date and time on the edit -- which will appear any time a post has been edited. It behaves no differently on questions than answers, it is identical.

The actual URL is as follows, just edit it to taste.

`http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/966/revisions`